# How tro translate Symfony 4 security error message: "Invalid credentials"

Tags: php, symfony, translation, symfony4, symfony-security

I am developing a Vue.js application and want to handle the login via JSON login. This works already but I'd like to translate the error messages, e.g. "Invalid credentials."

My `translation.yaml` config file.

```
framework:
    default_locale: de
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - en
```

The Symfony Security component already has some German (de) translations in its translation directory:

https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Resources/translations/security.de.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
        ...
            <trans-unit id="4">
                <source>Invalid credentials.</source>
                <target>Fehlerhafte Zugangsdaten.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        ...
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

So I copied this file into my `translations` directory but still the english messages are being displayed. Also I always cleared my cache (thanks to Dylan's answer)

Comment: You may need to clear your cache (even in the dev environment).

Comment: I did that already, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be displaying the message key which would always be in english. I guess you have to access translations and translate the message key.

In twig it looks like this:

```
 <span class="form-error-message">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</span>
```

In Vue.js I guess you'd have to expose the translations in JavaScript or JSON.

According to this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) you can also throw a `CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException` at any point in your LoginAuthenticator and customize the messages the way you want, which would make it possible to translate security errors on the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you should change the `source-language="en"` to `source-language="de"`.

Answer (score 0):

Translate according to this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#controlling-error-messages):

Create translation file `translations/security.de.yaml` and translate messages according to `vendor/symfony/security-core/Resources/translations/security.de.xlf`

```
'Invalid credentials.': 'The password you entered was invalid!'
```